# Is there a way to embed an Excel chart inside an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad

Is it possible for it to retain its display formatting, and links to Internet sites?

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView can display Excell documents.  Just open them like you would any other HTML file.  Not sure about the display formatting or links though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be a little bit different. If you have a way to get to the displayed data (e.g. parse the excel file, or if possible use a csv or plist). Then you could use [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) to display the data. I really like this SDK, because you can nearly customize everything. ;-)

Sandro